# plt.plot meaning of [:,0] and [:,1]

Tags: python, plot

I am plotting a graph using plt.plot using information found online.

However, I do not know what the y[:,0] means:

```
    plt.plot(t, y[:,0], label= 'active Mos')
```

Similarly, I see y[:,1] a lot too...

plt.plot is to plot a line to the graph, right?

Comment: Went through it but cannot see the , in the notation anywhere... if the , wasnt there i could understand but...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is a notation used in Numpy/Pandas.

`[ : , 0 ]` means (more or less) `[ first_row:last_row , column_0 ]`. If you have a 2-dimensional list/matrix/array, this notation will give you all values in column 0 (from all rows).